# Saving Signatures from forms to be emailed using asp classic

Tags: jquery, forms, email, asp-classic

I'm currently having trouble with embedding images into an email. Here's the workflow:

- User saves a form that lets them sign using a jquery plugin
  (http://keith-wood.name/signature.html)
- The form saves the image as a json object (which is stored server side). The reason we save the json string is because it's smaller than the base64 data and the signature gets repainted when displaying the previously saved form
- Some forms are emailed to admins, which brings the question, what is the best way to embed the image to the email?

I tried converting the image to base64 data and plugging that into the email body html, but only get a red 'X'

Is there a better practice for storing the signature into the db (sql server 2000) as well as plugging the saved image into an email??

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the image data in e-mail? Here is a sample `<img>` tag which I used for base64. Note: data is embedded into the img tag in this case.

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,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'/ >
```

Comment: So it turns out embedding a base64 image isn't supported across the board:
[link](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/)

I believe at this point the best thing is to attach the files to the email, or host it somewhere publicly and link them.